# Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, curvature, covariance

I am little bit confused on Riemann curvature tensor,

Riemann curvature tensor written in component form as;
$$R^d_{cab}=\partial_a\Gamma^d_{bc}-\partial_b\Gamma^d_{ac}+\Gamma^i_{bc}\Gamma^d_{ai}-\Gamma^i_{ac}\Gamma^d_{bi},$$ where $\Gamma^d_{bc}$ is affine connection.

My question is for the Riemann curvature tensor $R^d_{cab}$ to be a truly tensor there should be covariant derivative instead of partial derivative in those expression ? Such as
$$R^d_{cab}=\nabla_a\Gamma^d_{bc}-\nabla_b\Gamma^d_{ac}+\Gamma^i_{bc}\Gamma^d_{ai}-\Gamma^i_{ac}\Gamma^d_{bi}.$$

Comment: $\Gamma^a_{bc}$ doesn't transform as a tensor field, so you can't act covariant derivative on it

Answer (score 3):

The formula
$$R^d{}_{cab}=\partial_a\Gamma^d{}_{bc}-\partial_b\Gamma^d{}_{ac}
+\Gamma^i{}_{bc}\Gamma^d{}_{ai}-\Gamma^i{}_{ac}\Gamma^d{}_{bi} \tag{1}$$
actually is covariant, even though it doesn't look like this.

An equivalent (evidently covariant) [definition of the Riemann
curvature tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Coordinate_expression)
$R^d{}_{cab}$ is the Ricci identity
$$\nabla_b\nabla_a A_c-\nabla_a\nabla_b A_c=A_d R^d{}_{cab} \tag{2}$$
where $A_c$ is an arbitrary field and $\nabla_a$ is the covariant derivative.

From equation (2) together with the definition of the
covariant derivative $\nabla_a$ (in terms of $\partial_a$ and
$\Gamma^d{}_{bc}$) you can derive equation (1).

Comment: Are you sure about the sign? The formula you have linked expanded to the left and right is $\nabla_\sigma\nabla_\rho A_\nu-\nabla_\rho\nabla_\sigma A_\nu=A_{\nu;\rho\sigma} - A_{\nu;\sigma\rho} = A_\beta{R^\beta}_{\nu\rho\sigma}=-A_\beta{R^\beta}_{\nu\sigma\rho}$?

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz You are right. I have fixed the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the answer of Thomas Fritsch, this is how the calculation looks like in detail:
\begin{align*}
[\nabla_\mu,\nabla_\nu] A_\lambda
&=(\nabla_\mu\nabla_\nu-\nabla_\nu\nabla_\mu)A_\lambda
=\nabla_\mu(\partial_\nu A_\lambda-\Gamma_{\nu\lambda}^\rho A_\rho)
-\nabla_\nu(\partial_\mu A_\lambda-\Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^\rho A_\rho) \\
&=\partial_\mu(\partial_\nu A_\lambda-\Gamma_{\nu\lambda}^\rho A_\rho)
-\Gamma_{\mu\nu}^\tau(\partial_\tau A_\lambda-\Gamma_{\tau\lambda}^\rho A_\rho)
-\Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^\tau(\partial_\nu A_\tau-\Gamma_{\nu\tau}^\rho A_\rho) \\
&-\partial_\nu(\partial_\mu A_\lambda-\Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^\rho A_\rho)
+\Gamma_{\nu\mu}^\tau(\partial_\tau A_\lambda-\Gamma_{\tau\lambda}^\rho A_\rho)
+\Gamma_{\nu\lambda}^\tau(\partial_\mu A_\tau-\Gamma_{\mu\tau}^\rho A_\rho) \\
&=-\partial_\mu(\Gamma_{\nu\lambda}^\rho A_\rho)
-\Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^\tau(\partial_\nu A_\tau-\Gamma_{\nu\tau}^\rho A_\rho)
+\partial_\nu(\Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^\rho A_\rho)
+\Gamma_{\nu\lambda}^\tau(\partial_\mu A_\tau-\Gamma_{\mu\tau}^\rho A_\rho) \\
&=-\left(\partial_\mu\Gamma_{\nu\lambda}^\rho
-\partial_\nu\Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^\rho
+\Gamma_{\mu\tau}^\rho\Gamma_{\nu\lambda}^\tau
-\Gamma_{\nu\tau}^\rho\Gamma_{\mu\lambda}^\tau
\right)A_\rho
=-R_{\lambda\mu\nu}^\rho A_\rho.
\end{align*}
The left side transforms like a tensor, therefore the right side does as well and since $A$ is arbitary, so does the Riemann tensor. You can also prove that directly using the transformation formula of the Christoffel symbol, but that is more laborious. You can look at it [here](https://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/VALERIA/TEACHING/riemann.pdf).